# IOS audio session feasibility

Tags: ios, audio

I want to make an app which will have some settings option for volume control. When any app will start playing any sound even phone call then the sound volume will be according to volume of my app.
I want to make it in native iOS platform. Does it possible? If possible then any idea or resources How?

Comment: You cannot manipulate system settings or other apps' settings from within your app...

Comment: .. thank goodness. Imagine, an app that could silence my phone calls!

Comment: @BenClayton, What would be wrong with that?  Perhaps your intent was to silence those calls.  This idea of protecting everyone from themselves has done more harm than good, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iOS security sandbox will prevent your app from changing the audio settings (including volume) used by any other app.